# Dynamic update for different colums using between two date like calendar date

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalendarMonthly] 
(
    @FROMDATE VARCHAR(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ADate DATETIME
DECLARE @MonthCount INT

SET @ADate = @FROMDATE
SET @MonthCount = (SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(@ADate)))

DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE
    (       
    TRoomID INT,    DAY1 INT,   DAY2 INT,       DAY3 INT,   DAY4 INT,           DAY5 INT,   DAY6 INT,       DAY7 INT    
    )

    INSERT INTO @tmpTable

    SELECT RM.ROOMID,       
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0

        FROM RoomMaster AS RM
        LEFT JOIN RoomTypes AS RT ON RM.RoomTypeID = RT.RoomTypeID
             WHERE RM.RoomMasterStatus <> 99

DECLARE @RoomID INT
DECLARE @ForDate DATE
DECLARE @dtFromDate DATE
DECLARE @dtToDate DATE

SET @dtFromDate = CONVERT(DATE,@FromDate)
SET @ForDate = @dtFromDate
SET @dtToDate = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(@dtFromDate)) +'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(DATEADD(M,1,@dtFromDate)))+'-1')
SET @dtToDate = DATEADD(D,-1,@dtToDate)

DECLARE @DayCount INT

WHILE  @ForDate <= @dtToDate
    BEGIN

        SET @DayCount = DAY(@ForDate)

        IF @DayCount = 1
            BEGIN
                    -- Checkin
                    UPDATE @tmpTable SET DAY1 = 1

                    FROM @tmpTable TT
                    JOIN RoomCheckinDetails AS RCD ON RCD.RoomID = TT.TRoomID
                    JOIN RoomCheckinMaster AS RCM ON RCM.CheckinID = RCD.CheckinID
                        WHERE CONVERT(DATE,RCD.CheckinDate) = @ForDate 
                                AND  RCD.RoomID = TT.TRoomID

                    -- Expected Checkin
                    UPDATE @tmpTable SET DAY1 = 8

                    FROM @tmpTable TT
                    JOIN RoomBookingDetails AS RBD ON RBD.RoomID = TT.TRoomID
                    JOIN RoomBookingMaster AS RBM ON RBM.ReservationID = RBD.ReservationID
                        WHERE CONVERT(DATE,RBD.ExpectedCheckinDate) = @ForDate
                                AND  RBD.RoomID = TT.TRoomID            

            END
            ELSE IF @DayCount = 2
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            ---upto Day count 7


        SET @ForDate = DATEADD(Day,1,@ForDate)

    END


    SELECT * FROM @tmpTable


END
```

My question is:

ex: checkindate = 04/06/2017,  checoutdate = 9/06/2017 in compare two date I have update to columns day1 to columns day6 values is 0.

Comment: What is your input dataset and your expected output dataset? You might not require a loop mostly for doing this

Comment: Can you get a native english speaker to help you re-write your question?   I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a temporary table and using a cursor to update each set of columns, this is a set based solution that avoids all of that.

For the first part, if you just need 7 days then you can use a simple values tally table with a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql):

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170605';
;with dates as (
  select 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,rn-1,@fromdate))
    , rn 
  from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) t(rn)
)
```

Otherwise, you can generate an adhoc table of dates using stacked ctes in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) like this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170605';
declare @thrudate date = dateadd(day,6,@fromdate)

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
    , rn = row_number() over(order by (select 1))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                 cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
```

Then `cross join` the dates with `roommaster`, and `left join` both the checkin and booking tables to see if a room has a reservation or is currently occupied:

```
, cte as (
select 
    rm.roomid
  , d.rn
  , Value = case 
      when rcd.roomid is not null then 1
      when rbd.roomid is not null then 8
      else 0
      end
from dates d
  cross join roommaster rm
  left join roomcheckindetails rcd
    on rm.roomid = rcd.roomid 
   and d.date >= rcd.checkindate 
   and d.date <= rcd.checkoutdate
  left join roombookingdetails rbd
    on rm.roomid = rbd.roomid
   and d.date >= rbd.expectedcheckindate 
   and d.date <= rbd.expectedcheckoutdate
where rm.roommasterstatus <> 99
)
```

Then for the last piece, you can use conditional aggregation or `pivot()` (pick one) like so:

---

```
select 
    roomid
  , Day1 = min(case when rn = 1 then value end)
  , Day2 = min(case when rn = 2 then value end)
  , Day3 = min(case when rn = 3 then value end)
  , Day4 = min(case when rn = 4 then value end)
  , Day5 = min(case when rn = 5 then value end)
  , Day6 = min(case when rn = 6 then value end)
  , Day7 = min(case when rn = 7 then value end)
from cte
group by roomid
```

---

```
select 
    roomid
  , Day1 = [1]
  , Day2 = [2]
  , Day3 = [3]
  , Day4 = [4]
  , Day5 = [5]
  , Day6 = [6]
  , Day7 = [7]
from cte
  pivot (min(value) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]))p
```

rextester demo with conditional aggregation: http://rextester.com/RUJ98491

rextester demo with `pivot()`: http://rextester.com/YNKU89188

both return the same results for my demo data:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| roomid | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      2 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|      3 |    0 |    8 |    8 |    8 |    8 |    0 |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)